# Attaching collision object to robot gets crooked

Tags: ros, c++, ubuntu, ur10, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attaching a tool as a collision object to the robot (UR10), so far so good. But when it's attached the tool gets crooked relative to the robot. Please take a look at the pictures and code below. Do anyone else have this problem, can't find a similar problem. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, ROS-indigo and C++ for programming.

[Picture 1 http://minfil.org/M1a0jfbbba/Screenshot_-_2015-07-15_-_09_08_08.png](http://minfil.org/M1a0jfbbba/Screenshot_-_2015-07-15_-_09_08_08.png)

[Picture2 http://minfil.org/Nba7jebfbc/Screenshot_-_2015-07-15_-_09_08_36.png](http://minfil.org/Nba7jebfbc/Screenshot_-_2015-07-15_-_09_08_36.png)

```
      //MESH
  moveit_msgs::CollisionObject co;
 co.header.frame_id = group.getPlanningFrame();
 co.id = "Mounter";

shapes::Mesh* m = shapes::createMeshFromResource("package://ur_description/meshes/ur10/visual/mounter.stl");
shape_msgs::Mesh co_mesh;
shapes::ShapeMsg co_mesh_msg;
shapes::constructMsgFromShape(m,co_mesh_msg);
co_mesh = boost::get<shape_msgs::Mesh>(co_mesh_msg);
co.meshes.resize(1);
co.meshes[0] = co_mesh;
co.mesh_poses.resize(1);
co.mesh_poses[0].position.x = -0.39;
co.mesh_poses[0].position.y = -0.777;
co.mesh_poses[0].position.z = 0.3115;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 0.0;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 3.14;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= -3.1415;
//pub_co.publish(co);

co.meshes.push_back(co_mesh);
co.mesh_poses.push_back(co.mesh_poses[0]);
co.operation = co.ADD;
std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects3; 
collision_objects3.push_back(co);  

// Now, let's add the collision object into the world
ROS_INFO("Adding Mounter to world");  
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects3);
sleep(5);


ROS_INFO("Attach the tool to the robot");
group.attachObject("Mounter", "ee_link");
```

We have done the same test with basicshape cylinders instead of a mesh as collision object without this problem.

```
moveit_msgs::CollisionObject collision_object1;
collision_object1.header.frame_id = group.getPlanningFrame();
collision_object1.id = "cylinder2";

/* Define a box to add to the world. */
shape_msgs::SolidPrimitive primitive1;
primitive1.type = primitive1.CYLINDER;
primitive1.dimensions.resize(2);
primitive1.dimensions[0] = 0.13;
primitive1.dimensions[1] = 0.06;

/* A pose for the box (specified relative to frame_id) */
geometry_msgs::Pose cylinder_pose1;
cylinder_pose1.orientation.w = 0;
cylinder_pose1.position.x = -0.39;
cylinder_pose1.position.y = -0.78;
cylinder_pose1.position.z = -0.025;

collision_object1.primitives.push_back(primitive1);
collision_object1.primitive_poses.push_back(cylinder_pose1);
collision_object1.operation = collision_object1.ADD;

std::vector<moveit_msgs::CollisionObject> collision_objects1;
collision_objects1.push_back(collision_object1);

ROS_INFO("Add cylinder into the world");
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects);
sleep(2);

ROS_INFO("Add cylinder into the world");
planning_scene_interface.addCollisionObjects(collision_objects1);
sleep(2);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213754/attaching-collision-object-to-robot-gets-crooked/) by [JonasPallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23177/jonaspallis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.w= 0.0;
> ```

```
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.x= 0.0;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.y= 3.14;
co.mesh_poses[0].orientation.z= -3.1415;
```

Poses in ROS are preferably encoded as [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), **not** [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). The [moveit_msgs/CollisionObject](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/moveit_msgs/html/msg/CollisionObject.html) message uses arrays of [geometry_msgs/Pose](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Pose.html) messages to store those poses.

From your code snippet, I get the idea that you tried to assign Euler angle rotations around the Y and Z-axis. That won't work (as you noticed). If you want to continue using Euler angles, you can convert them to a quaternion before assigning them to the `co.mesh_poses` array elements.

---

Edit:

> ```
> group.attachObject("Mounter", "ee_link");
> ```

It might also be an idea to attach your object to the `tool0` link of the UR10 model, instead of `ee_link`. The `tool0` link was recently introduced ([universal_robot/pull#200](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/200)) and is oriented in such a way that it corresponds to the default (all-zeros) toolframe of the UR10.

---

Edit2: see [Transform Quaternion](http://answers.ros.org/question/50113/transform-quaternion/) fi for some hints on how to perform the conversion.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonasPallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23177/jonaspallis/) on 2015-07-15**:
Using the new universal_robot folder with tool0 instead of ee_link did unfortunately not solve the problem. We will use tool0 in the future anyway.

I guess that our problem lies with the `co.mesh_poses`. When we did this test with two basic cylinders instead of a .stl we did not have this problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-15**:
So I'm confused: are you or are you not using a quaternion for the pose in your 'stl mesh' code excerpt? Cause those values in the `.y` and `.z` fields of the `orientation` field seem rather strange for a quaternion.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-15**:\

> Using the new universal_robot folder with tool0 instead of ee_link did unfortunately not solve the problem.

I wasn't suggesting it would. I just thought I'd mention the new frames, as they are oriented somewhat more intuitively than `ee_link` and the `base_link`.

**Comment by [JonasPallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23177/jonaspallis/) on 2015-07-15**:
We are using Euler. We tried  different `.y` and `.z`  values until the tool was placed correctly. Isn't this just the initial position? Does these coordinates matter when the robot has picked the tool up?

**Comment by [JonasPallis](https://answers.ros.org/users/23177/jonaspallis/) on 2015-07-15**:
We got the code from [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/204770/insert-obstacle-in-step-format-into-moveit-via-c-node/).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-15**:
You cannot treat the `pose.orientation` field as a set of Euler angles. It just doesn't work. Please read the answer to the question I linked to earlier, it should show you how to convert from a roll-pitch-yaw triplet to a quaternion, which you can then use for the `orientation` field.